# backbone routing not working on refresh

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have put this demo together

http://demo.stg.brightonconsulting.net.au/templates/tests/backboneJQMProducts/

at the moment only the top link 'products json pull' works. if you click that you are taken to a new page (http://demo.stg.brightonconsulting.net.au/templates/tests/backboneJQMProducts/index.html#products/productList)

the routing to this page works ok but when you refresh the page it doesnt show that page it just shows a blank page? (it is refreshes ok - do a cntr+f5 and you will see)

has anyone had this before/does anyone know what the fix is?

I have tried editing this code

```
define(['jquery','underscore', 'backbone','router'],
function($, _, Backbone,Router) {

var init=function(){
    //create backbone router
    //location.hash = '';
    var router=new Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
};

return{
    initialize:init
}
});
```

based on recomendations.

I am using require.js to put the app together and this is called from the main.js which is instantiated by require

```
require.config({

paths: {
    jquery:     'vendor/jqm/jquery_1.7_min',
    jqm:     'vendor/jqm/jquery.mobile-1.1.0', 
    underscore: 'vendor/underscore/underscore_amd',
    backbone:   'vendor/backbone/backbone_amd',
    text:       'vendor/require/text',
    plugin:    'plugin',
    templates:  '../templates',
    views:    '../views',
    models:       '../models'
}

});


define(['app','jqm-config'], function(app) {
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("DOM IS READY");// Handler for .ready() called.
});    
app.initialize();
});
```

thanks dan

Comment: I cant reproduce the error on my chrome.

Comment: Happens on my ff and more importantly on my phone.. Means can send people to a direct link which is useless... Could it be to do with the way I am using require.js and the define method?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this. I am also facing the same issue. None of the below answers helped me. Please revert

Comment: @sSaroj Did u solve this issue?

Comment: @vini Nope. I didn't.

Answer (score 6):

I've just encountered something similar after setting up BackboneJS with RequireJS.

I was calling `Backbone.history.start()` from inside my router code; to fix the problem, I moved this call to be after where I instantiate my view in my main `require()` function.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

You can do two things, depending on the behaviour you want to achieve:

Reset the hash before you initialize your routing.

```
location.hash = ''
var router=new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

You can navigate to that hash tag after you initialize your routing.

```
var router=new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
router.navigate(location.hash, true)
```

Comment: hi thanks for this..

if i try both of these it doesnt show a blank page but does re route me to the beginning of my application... 

I really want it to stay on the page I am on..

Comment: @sebastian https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320519/backbone-route-with-push-state-not-working-on-page-refresh Could you help me with this