# Page refresh takes to blank page in Backbone.js

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have an application in backbone.js. If I refresh any page with the # tags, the content of the page disappears. Can anyone suggest any solution for this.

Here are the codes of my main.js and app.js

main.js

```
require.config({
        paths: {
        jquery:     'libs/jqm/jquery-1.9.1.min',
        async:      'libs/require/async',
        jqm:        'libs/jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-alpha.2.min',
        iscroll:    'libs/iscroll/iscroll',
        underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore_amd',
        backbone:   'libs/backbone/backbone_1.1.0_min',
        text:       'libs/require/text',
    }
});
require(['app', 'jqm-config'], function(app) {
        app.initialize();
});
```

app.js

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'router'], function($, _, Backbone, Router) {
    'use strict';
    var init=function(){
        var router = new Router();
        Backbone.history.start();
    };
    return{
        initialize:init
    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

May be it is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376773/backbone-routing-not-working-on-refresh). But none of the suggestions worked for me.

Comment: can you please post the content of your router

Comment: also is any error being thrown at the console?

Comment: no error in the console Rayweb_on. And the router content is huge. I have navigation # tags and normal $el.html().

Answer (score 0):

I added **async: false** to each of the fetch method and it resolved.